# Find pattern in string and extract following value

Tags: r, string

In R, I need to find the next value by a code in the string

**Example 1 with C**

```
function("C", "01_BP01_C_2_MMAX_8__TIME_SECONDS_1.json")
```

solution: 2

**Example 2 with MMAX**

```
function("MMAX", "01_BP01_C_2_MMAX_8__TIME_SECONDS_1.json")
```

solution: 8

**Example 3 with MMAX**

```
function("MMAX", "01_BP01_C_2_MMAX_12__TIME_SECONDS_1.json")
```

solution: 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is custom function based on `strpslit`:

```
getResult <- function(pattern, target, splitPattern = "_") {
    foo <- unlist(strsplit(target, splitPattern))
    foo[which(foo == pattern) + 1]
}
# Returns 2 
getResult("C", "01_BP01_C_2_MMAX_8__TIME_SECONDS_1.json")
# Returns 8
getResult("MMAX", "01_BP01_C_2_MMAX_8__TIME_SECONDS_1.json")
```

Comment: This solution results wonderfully
Thank you very much :)

Comment: @BorisAlmonacid If it solved your problem you can accept my answer then :-)

Answer (score 1):

With `gsub` and a regular expression you could do it this way:

```
str <- c("01_BP01_C_2_MMAX_8__TIME_SECONDS_1.json", 
         "01_BP01_C_2_MMAX_8__TIME_SECONDS_1.json",
         "01_BP01_C_2_MMAX_12__TIME_SECONDS_1.json")

pat <- c("C", "MMAX", "MMAX")

splt <- function(pattern, string) {
  as.numeric(gsub(paste0("^.*?", pattern, ".*?(\\d+).*"), "\\1", string))
}

sapply(1:length(str), function(x) splt(pat[x], str[x]))

[1]  2  8 12
```